# Continuity and its inverse function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1) \cup [2,3] \to \mathbb R$

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x &: x\in [0,1)\\
x-1&: x\in[2,3]
\end{cases}$

Show that $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $[0,1) \cup [2,3]$ and that its inverse function $f^-1 : [0,2] \to [0,1) \cup [2,3]$ is discontinuous in $x_0 = 1$

My thoughts:

I think that I can show the continuity by one-sided limits, and strictly increasing by  $x<y$, $f(x)<f(y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work.

Here is a sketch of the graphs of $f$ (red), $f^{-1}$ (yellow) and $\text{id}$ (grey):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your method of proving continuity and monotonicity of the function is right.  However, the inverse function is 
$f^{-1}(x)=x,x\in[0,1)$ and $f^{-1}= x+1, x\in [1,2]$. So, at $x=1, f^{-1}(x)=2$, but it approaches $1$ from the left, thus proving discontinuity at $x_0=1$.